# Zend_Auth: not working, getDbSelect() is empty

Tags: zend-framework, zend-auth

my authentication fails and when i try to getDbSelect() i get nothing ... what did i do wrong?

```
class AuthController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    protected $auth;

    public function init()
    {
        $db = $this->getInvokeArg("bootstrap")->getResource("db");
        $this->auth = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($db, 'users', 'username', 'password', 'md5(?)');
    }
    public function loginAction()
    {
        if (isset($_POST["username"])) {
            $result = $this->auth
                ->setIdentity($this->getRequest()->getParam('username'))
                ->setCredential($this->getRequest()->getParam('password'));
            echo " > " . $this->auth->getDbSelect();die();
            $result = $this->auth
                ->setIdentity($this->getRequest()->getParam('username'))
                ->setCredential($this->getRequest()->getParam('password'))
                ->authenticate();
            if ($result->isValid()) {
                $this->_redirect("postLogin");
            }
        }
    }
```

## Update 1:

i also tried without MVC and with MySQL which i am more familiar with:

```
// setup auto loading
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

// setup db connection
$db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(array(
    'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname'   => 'learnZendAuth'
));

// create authentication adapter
$auth = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($db, 'users', 'username', 'password', 'md5(?)');

// do login if request is posted
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
    // do authencation
    $result = $auth->setIdentity($_POST['username'])
         ->setCredential($_POST['password'])
         ->authenticate();

    // check authentication valid
    if ($result->isValid()) {
        // login success
        echo "successfully logged in as: " . $result->getIdentity();
    } else {
        // login fail
        echo "";
        print_r($result->getMessages());
        echo "";
    }
} else {
    // request not posted
    // see if already logged in
    if (Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()) {
        echo "already logged in as: " . Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity();
    }
}
```

i get

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Zend_Auth_Adapter_Exception' with
>   message 'The supplied parameters to
>   Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable failed to
>   produce a valid sql statement, please
>   check table and column names for
>   validity.' in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Auth\Adapter\DbTable.php:414
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Auth\Adapter\DbTable.php(306):
>   Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable->_authenticateQuerySelect(Object(Zend_Db_Select))
>
> ## 1 C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\learnZf\index.php(23):
>
> Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable->authenticate()
>
> ## 2 {main} thrown in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Auth\Adapter\DbTable.php
>
> on line 414

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh i found out what i did wrong ...

the 1st try, i used Sqlite, and it does not support md5(?) treatment

the 2nd try, i specified wrong column names ... name vs username ...

Answer (score 0):

try and move the getDbSelect in the is valid statement, 
also i normally use

```
$userInfo = $this->auth->getResultRowObject();
```

to get the user info, never saw this getDbSelect method